# Problems connecting to MySQL from time to time

Tags: java, mysql, exception, database-connection

I've a java program that connects to MySQL 5.0 a lot of times.
I use mysql-connector-5.0.8.jar file to do it.

From time to time, and it's not with a specific period, I've got the following exception:

```
Last packet sent to the server was 1 ms ago.
2014/01/09 11:43:50:536 ERROR [com.bnpparibas.peach.core.EventDispatcherThread:3] EventDispatcherThread - org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:599)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:374)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:263)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:101)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at $Proxy18.persistFeed(Unknown Source)
        at com.bnpparibas.peach.core.FeedConfiguratorImpl.persistFeed(FeedConfiguratorImpl.java:102)
        at com.bnpparibas.peach.core.EventFeedImpl.persistIfNeeded(EventFeedImpl.java:117)
        at com.bnpparibas.peach.core.EventDispatcherThread.run(EventDispatcherThread.java:35)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:74)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:29)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:420)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:129)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:57)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1290)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:558)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception:

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **

java.net.UnknownHostException
MESSAGE: machine.fr.net.intra

STACKTRACE:

java.net.UnknownHostException: machine.fr.net.intra
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1158)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1084)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1020)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:246)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:271)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2771)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1148)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:82)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:417)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:129)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:57)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1290)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:558)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:374)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:263)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:101)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at $Proxy18.persistFeed(Unknown Source)
        at com.bnpparibas.peach.core.FeedConfiguratorImpl.persistFeed(FeedConfiguratorImpl.java:102)
        at com.bnpparibas.peach.core.EventFeedImpl.persistIfNeeded(EventFeedImpl.java:117)
        at com.bnpparibas.peach.core.EventDispatcherThread.run(EventDispatcherThread.java:35)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
```

Do you know how can I solve this issue?

Or point me in a direction to solve it ^^

Comment: does that machine changes its IP address from time to time? Or may be a DNS problem?

Comment: `UnknownHostException: machine.fr.net.intra` Quote from [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/UnknownHostException.html) "Thrown to indicate that the IP address of a host could not be determined."

Comment: It's definitely your DNS problem / IP change

Comment: Yeah I guess it's a DNS problem. Can you always resolve the IP of `machine.fr.net.intra` manually, leaving your application out of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed a DNS problem.
Changing to the ip address worked as a charm.